"Clone with related" button does not work on Product page
We are facing an issue when trying to clone a Product with ist related lists.
It is a CPQ button : (Button or Link URL    /apex/SBQQ__CloneProductChildren?id={!Product2.Id})

It is strange because there are standard price book entries for the cloned product.
Any idea on the reason why this error is triggered ?
Best regards

The reason for the error was that there were some inactive standard price book entries related to the product about to be cloned. We reactivated those standard price book entries and it worked.
